# Authenticate HTTP requests

Tags: http, security

I'm developing an API that receives HTTP requests from the Internet. One of the problems I'm facing is how to authenticate those requests in order to know that they are actually coming from a specific IP address.

- I have read the X-Forwarded-For header is not safe at all
- RSA does not prevent Man in the Middle
- What I'm doing is: given an id and a password, both parameters are sent in each request so the system can validate the request, but I think it's not the best option at all.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You say you want to "know that they are actually coming from a specific IP address". Is the IP address actually what's important, or do you really want to know the request is from a specific user?

Comment: The IP is what's really important.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's truly the IP address that you're needing to authenticate, and not any sort of user, then HTTP is too high on the networking stack. You need something like IPSec or WireGuard to authenticate IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to redirect user to authenticate on HTTPS server that generates a token for him and then with that token request the infos on the HTTP server, so even a man in the middle can obtain current session and when the user logout it is useless.

And then you can even validate the IP from login on HTTPS on each HTTP request.

Edit: I think the whole process is explained really well [here](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/Europe/events/foaf-galway/papers/fp/token_based_authentication/)

Comment: HTTPS doesn't give you any assurance of the client's true IP address. This is obvious because it works through NAT.